# HI, I am not able to call redshift stored procedure in SSIS ExecuteSqltask

Tags: stored-procedures, amazon-redshift, connection-string, google-assistant-sdk, execute-sql-task

I am getting this error, while calling  stored procedure of Redshift. we are using oledb connection

Error: 0xC002F210 at Execute SQL Task 1, Execute SQL Task: Executing the query "call dev.proc_test" failed with the following error: "Undefined procedure proc_test". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.
Task failed: Execute SQL Task 1

I have  set result set as none because my procedure is not returning any value.
I have called the procedure with db name.
In my Redshift db procedure is saving under functions tab.
Is that the  reason for my error? why my procedure is saving under the functions, how to rectify this

Comment: You may need to append the DB name to the SP  EXEC DBName.dbo.proc_test.

Answer (score 0):

I have called the  procedure with the DB name ,It is working fine
[image]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hWpl.png

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).